# How to avoid user change window size without define ResizeMode="NoResize"

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF window. 
I want to disable the ResizeMode from the user, that means, I want to ignore any resize that the user will try to do but I want to leave the ResizeMode as "CanResizeWithGrip".

How to do this?

Comment: You could subscribe to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged.aspx and then revert the changed. since the even is fired multiple times while resizing this would have something like a flickering result

Comment: You can just draw that grip.

Comment: Why do you want to give the illusion of resizing the window to the user?

Answer (score 1):

Set pair values `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth` and/or `MinHeight` and `MaxHeight` to the same value. Like that you can even specify separately if user can resize vertically, horizontally or cannot resize at all

Comment: no can do .. because my window hold 2 controls - each of them with different size - and i need to change the window size in run time. so i need to change the window to w=X1, h=Y1 size and to w=X2, h=Y2

Comment: So don't set them in XAML. Set them instead of `Width` and `Height` in code at runtime. Before you change the `Window` size disable constrains and after resize fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below code on the load event of the window:

```
        this.MaxWidth = this.Width;
        this.MaxHeight = this.Height;
```

It will solve your problem. I hope it will help you. :)